# addEventListener and interrupts

Tags: javascript, c++, c

i am building a small game.
I have a `while()` function running all the the time,
and need to know what happens when an
`addEventlistenner ( 'message' , HandleMessage , true)` or any other addEventListener is fired up in the background?

Does it work like a interrupt , will finish executing `HandleMessage` and then go back to my  while() ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a while() function running all the the time, and need to know
>   what happens when an addEventlistenner ( 'message' , HandleMessage ,
>   true) or any other addEventListener is fired up in the background?

If `while` loop is an infinite loop then there is no chance that your event handler will ever be invoked.

JS execution in browser is only a single threaded operation and when any asynchronous operation is requested/invoked, it goes into a an **even-loop queue**. Which means that unless the current `while` loop has finished other tasks which have lined up in the **event-loop queue** will not be fired.

So, if your while loop is infinite, events added via `addEventListener` will never be executed even if they are invoked.